# My php Contact form isn't working properly

Tags: php, html

The contact form will only send an email will the words name email and message. I have been going over it for a few hours but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the contact php file (email is edited)

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'outlook.com';
$subject = 'Message about Tejano Fest '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
  window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
```

Here is the html segment it's related to:

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#contact">
    <div class="left">
        <label for="author">Name:</label> 
        <input name="author" type="text" class="input_field" id="author" maxlength="40" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <label for="email">Email:</label> 
        <input name="email" type="text" class="input_field" id="email" maxlength="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There is no field called cf_name, cf_email and cf_message. `$mail_to` should be an email.

Comment: `isn't working properly` is not a easily diagnosable problem.

Comment: Sorry about the vague title description. I was trying to avoid creating a title that was a paragraph long so I described the problem in the actual comment box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change it (there are the name of input):

```
$field_name = $_POST['author'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['text'];
```

Enjoy your code!

Comment: Dont mention it.
Enjoy your code! :)

(Can you put ok check in my reply, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Use this... your POST array values does not matching with your form field names .

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#contact">
<div class="left">
    <label for="author">Name:</label> 
    <input name="cf_name" type="text" class="input_field" id="author" maxlength="40" />
</div>
<div class="right">
    <label for="email">Email:</label> 
    <input name="cf_email" type="text" class="input_field" id="email" maxlength="80" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="cf_message" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$field_name = $_POST['author'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['text'];

$mail_to = 'test@outlook.com';
$subject = 'Message about Tejano Fest '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
  window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
} }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other option to consider(of course after changing the values of the POST arrays), you may want to try using PhpMailer-http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsendmail as maybe your hosting solution requires Smtp authourisation.

Comment: Naw i got it fixed. Its always the simple things that will trip you up. Thanks